# Text stuck to bottom of Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, divider

EDIT: Thanks guys, I've worked it out - it was a much more simple fix than your suggestions. Just needed to move the text into the 'maps' div (rather than the 'flex-container' div), and it put the text right underneath. Thanks for the help, it made me think the issue out!

So at the bottom of my website, I've got a div section that has a Google Map, and underneath it is supposed to be text saying the email address and physical address (of the business).

Unfortunately, that text is randomly being pushed right down to the bottom, as seen at the very bottom of this website:

http://website.sme.sh.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Below is the code that I think is affecting it -

```css
.page {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.map {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page get-in-touch">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="map">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2482.2326378518164!2d-0.08973764855540126!3d51.52729277953841!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48761ca5df3ab397%3A0xb76b90b168bccd4d!2sSmesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1528291922909" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <a href="mailto:hello@sme.sh" style="color: #000;"><u>hello@sme.sh</u></a> <a style="color: #000;"> | 20 East Road, London, N1 6AD</a>
</div>
```

Is there something I've missed out in my code?

Comment: `.flex-container { height: 100vh;` - you asked for one full screen height for the container you placed the map in, so you got one full screen height for the container you placed the map in …

Comment: Right - this was done as I wanted the map to always be vertically centred in the div (regardless of screen size). Can I not just get the text to do the same, but underneath the map?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `<a href="mailto:"></a>` tag and your address tag being outside of the `flex-container` class.

**To fix**, put the two `<a>` tags inside the `flex-container` class and position them how you'd like.

[image]

Or, reduce the `height` of your `flex-container` class

Comment: Thanks. The issue with this though is that it forces the map and text to squash side-by side with each other. I can't seem to get the text to just sit underneath the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
 
 
 .page {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.map {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page get-in-touch">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="map">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2482.2326378518164!2d-0.08973764855540126!3d51.52729277953841!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48761ca5df3ab397%3A0xb76b90b168bccd4d!2sSmesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1528291922909" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
 <p><a href="mailto:hello@sme.sh" style="color: #000;"><u>hello@sme.sh</u></a> <a style="color: #000;"> | 20 East Road, London, N1 6AD</a></p>
        </div>  
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not random. The text are supposed to be there as you have a `flex-container` before the `<a>` tag. Inside the `flex-container`, you have the map only `50%` in `height`, so it makes you feel like random when you have different screen/resolution.

You can either move the `<a>` inside the `flex-container` or you can give the map class `100%` in `height`

```css
.page {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.map {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page get-in-touch">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="map">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2482.2326378518164!2d-0.08973764855540126!3d51.52729277953841!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48761ca5df3ab397%3A0xb76b90b168bccd4d!2sSmesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1528291922909" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <a href="mailto:hello@sme.sh" style="color: #000;"><u>hello@sme.sh</u></a> <a style="color: #000;"> | 20 East Road, London, N1 6AD</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the .map height and width to 100% and use padding for whitespace around the map.
[image]

> **Explanation:**
>
> The main problem was that the map was in a flex container which had a
>   defined height and the map used only like 60% of the height. That's
>   the reason for the empty space between the map and your Text.

Any Questions? :)

**EDIT**
My Bad the only real Step that is necessary is the .map height and width.
I removed the other Instructions to avoid unecessery confussion.